# How can I merge observables once an item in the first observable satisfies a predicate?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to take two observables, and emit from the first observable until one of the items meets a predicate, and then start emitting events merged from both, like this:

```
letters:     -A----B---C----d---------e-----f------g--
numbers:     ---1-------2----------3-----4-----5------
predicate:   IsLowerCase()
result:      -A----B---C----d12----3--e--4--f--5---g--
```

How would it be possible to do this in C# using System.Reactive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` is almost always the key:

```
var letters = new Subject<string>();
var numbers = new Subject<string>();
var predicate = lettersPublished.Select(s => s.All(c => char.IsLower(c)));

var numbersCached = numbers.Replay().RefCount();

var dummySubscription = numbersCached.Subscribe();

var combined = lettersPublished.Merge(numbersCached);

var switchFlag = predicate.Where(b => b).Take(1);

var result = switchFlag.StartWith(false).Select(b => b ? combined : letters).Switch();

var resultWithDisposal = Observable.Using(() => dummySubscription, _ => result);
```

Construct the two observables, one before the predicate is true (`letters` in your case), and one after (`combined`), then use an observable to switch between them (`switchflag`). The `dummySubscription` is necessary to get `Replay` to cache all values prior to the latter subscription. `Using` is used to dump the `dummySubscription`.

You can also do this all in a single expression (given `letters` and `numbers`) as follows:

```
var oneLiner = letters.Publish(_letters => numbers.Replay(_numbers =>  
    _letters
        .Select(s => s.All(c => char.IsLower(c)))
        .Where(b => b)
        .Take(1)
        .StartWith(false)
        .Select(b => b ? _letters.Merge(_numbers) : letters)
        .Switch()
));
```

Comment: Switch is what I was missing.  Thanks!